# How to using productFlavors in android library with gradle plugin 3.5.1

Tags: android, gradle

I am using the gradle productFlavors in my library project like this.

[image]

and when i use the library in my app like this
[image]

and the error comes out:

Could not find method platformDebugImplementation() for arguments [DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':patientlib'', configuration='platformDebug'}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.